# Is there any way to limit data usage to xMB in sd card?

Tags: memory

I am using an 8gb card but want to limit usage to 4gb, meaning I want to delete old files which cross the 4gb mark. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I doubt that this is really a Pi-specific question and would suit better to the general Unix&Linux SE. I would however limit your desire to delete files based on age only. Might turn out that you deleted important config files ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any automated system is likely to be dangerous if you don't limit your data files to known directories.

Suppose you keep all your data files under /data then

> sudo find /data/* -ctime +14 -delete

will delete all files more than 14 days old.

I suggest you find an appropriate value for 14 to limit the amount of data stored to the size you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will return to you after i have got my results.

Comment: The date remains correct when i turn RPi off and on again, but the time doesn't. Is it possible to fix the time or keep it running with real time?

Comment: The Pi doesn't have a real-time clock.  If it is networked it'll use network time to re-sync its clock.  If it's not networked you could add an I2C real-time clock (RTC) module.  If you can't rely on the time you'll have to do something like name your data files in sequence, e.g. file1, file2, file3 etc.  and use the file name to determine the oldest file rather than the file's time-stamp.